# How does primitive array work with new for each loop in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I understand that new for each loop works with Iterable and arrays, but I don't know what goes behind the scenes when working with arrays.

Can anyone help me understand this?  Thanks in advance.

```
int[] number = new int[10];

for(int i: number) {

}
```

Comment: BTW, it would have helped if you had commented why the question was down voted.

Comment: upvoted, if find it interesting, especially if its equivalent on byte code basis to a normal (efficient) loop. But this nobody has answered exactly.

Answer (score 16):

The loop is equivalent to:

```
for(int j = 0; j < number.length; j++) {
  int i = number[j];
  ...
}
```

where j is an internally generated reference that does not conflict with normal user identifiers.

Comment: Is this true for arrays of reference types as well? E.g. will Java internally use this implementation on an Object[], or will it do something else (like convert it to an Iterable)?

Comment: @Karakuri I'm not even claiming this is how it is actually implemented for primitive arrays, just that the required behavior is equivalent. The required behavior for `Object[]` is also equivalent.

Answer (score 11):

A bit late, but here it is.

The compiler knows if you are using the for-each loop statement for a collection or for an array.

If used for collection,
the compiler translates the for-each loop to the equivalent for loop using an `Iterator`.

If used for an array,
the compiler translates the for-each loop to the equivalent for loop using an index variable.

[Here is a description at oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you allocate an array of 10 integers in the memory and obtain a reference to it. In the for-loop you simply iterate over every item in the array, which initially will be 0 for all the items. The value of every item will be stored in the variable `i` declared in your for-loop as you iterate the array elements.

Answer (score 2):

this is equivalent to:

```
for(int x = 0; x < number.length; x++) {
  int i = number[x];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the equivalent to:

```
final int len = number.length;
for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
  int i = number[j];
}
```

Note that the forEach will not evaluate the .length in each loop.
This might be also be eliminated by the JVM, but especially in case of collections,
where some would use

```
for(int j = 0; j < collection.size(); j++) {
```

it makes a (small) difference to the faster

```
int len = collection.size()
for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of for each loop not evaluating length every time.

Answer (score 0):

The for each over arrays is essentially "sugar" over this construct:

```
for(int i = 0;i<number.length;i++)
{  
}
```

I would imagine this was provided as a construct of the language so that people could use the enhanced for loop over a structure that was iterated over in the old way.

Comment: That would give i the values 0 through length-1. It should be taking the values of the array elements, all 0 in the example code.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan incorrect, there is no code inside my braces.  I was explaining the construct that was occurring behind the sugar

Answer (score 0):

`IntStream.range(1,4)` can be used, if using java 8.