# Do array types in Java have `forEach()` method, just as `Iterable` does?

Tags: java

foreach loop works for both `Iterable` interface and array types.

It works by calling the `forEach` method of `Iterable` interface.

Do array types in Java have `forEach()` method, just as `Iterable` does? Does foreach loop work for array types also by `forEach` method of array types?

I have read [How does primitive array work with new for each loop in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265888/how-does-primitive-array-work-with-new-for-each-loop-in-java), but I am not sure if it answers my question.

Comment: `array`  is a primitive type and primitive types does not have any methods

Comment: array types are reference types, not primitive types

Comment: you can use Arrays.stream. e.g. Arrays.stream(new int[]{1,2,3,4}).forEach(it -> System.out.println(it));

Comment: @Joe [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8) are of reference type, and whether they are arrays of primitive or reference types, they have the following methods, most but not all inherited from `java.lang.Object`: `clone()`, `hashCode()`, `equals()`, `toString()`, `wait()`, `notify()`, `notifyAll()`, ... In addition, they implement the `Serializable` and `Cloneable` interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `forEach` method introduced in Java 8 in the `Iterable` interface has nothing to do with what you call "foreach loop" (the actual name is enhanced for loop).

The enhanced for loop was introduced in an earlier Java version, and doesn't use the `forEach()` method. It uses the `iterator()` method implemented by classes that implement `Iterable`. For arrays it works without an iterator. It just uses the indices of the array to loop over the elements.

Comment: Thanks. When is `forEach` method of `Iterable` used, if it is not used in foreach loop?

Comment: @Ben when you write code that uses it + some JDK code that uses it - for example, `Collections.CheckedCollection<E>` calls it (I just ran a search and found out).

Comment: Is it correct that code that calls `forEach` method of `Iterable` is always replaceable by code using foreach loop?

Comment: @Ben I believe it is. You can always dump the body of the Consumer passed to the `forEach()` method into the body of a foreach loop.

Answer (score 3):

> foreach loop works for both Iterable interface and array types.

Correct.

> It works by calling the forEach method of Iterable interface.

No it doesn't.

> Do array types in Java have forEach() method, just as Iterable does?

No. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8) for details of what they have.

> Does foreach loop work for array types also by forEach method of array types?

No.

> I have read How does primitive array work with new for each loop in Java?, but I am not sure if it answers my question.

It does.