# how to solve this error in enhanced for loop in java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I wrote a simple retrieval  for loop for array list

```java
int[] a = new int[5] ;
for(int d:a)
{  
  Arrays.fill(a, 111);
  System.out.print(d);
}
```

The output of above code is  `0111111111111`.

I just can't figure out what is that 0 doing. My expected output is  `111111111111`.

When I write the same code using simple for loop

```
int[] a = new int[5] ;
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{  
  Arrays.fill(a, 111);
  System.out.print(a[i]);
}
```

it meets my expectation. I would like to know where I'm wrong.

Comment: Consider when "d" gets its first value.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if you wrote this intentionally, but filling the whole array each iteration, seems a bit odd to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35003339/1531124) explains that in the end, for arrays, the enhanced for-each is "basically" the same as using a conventional for loop with counter.

But the essential difference is: the enhanced for loop has to **pick** the first array entry, to put it into the `d` variable, **before** the loop body is entered.

In your second example, **no** value is retrieved from the array **before** the array gets updated. In the first example, one value is retrieved (and later printed) before the array gets filled with 1s.

That is all there is to this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) for the description of the enhanced for loop.

For an array, it says the equivalent basic for loop is:

```
// This loop...
for (TargetType Identifier : Expression) {
    Statement
}

// ...is equivalent to this:
T[] #a = Expression;
L1: L2: ... Lm:
for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
    {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
    Statement
}
```

Substituting your first loop into this:

```
// T[] #a = Expression;
T[] aa = a;

// You have no labels, so no need for the L1: L2 line.

// for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
for (int i = 0; i < aa.length; ++i) {
  // {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
  int d = aa[i];

  // Statement is your loop body:
  Arrays.fill(a, 111);
  System.out.print(d);
}
```

If you look at it like this, you can see that `d` is assigned before the `Arrays.fill(a, 111);` statement. As such, `d` isn't affected by the `fill`.

Comment: I understand now

Answer (score 0):

First is equivalent to:

```
int[] a = new int[5] ;
for(int i=0; i< a.length; i++)
{  
 int d=a[i];
 Arrays.fill(a, 111);
 System.out.print(d);
}
```